# Совместимость плагина с Vue-3. Как узнать, если явно не указано?

Tags: плагин, vue3, совместимость

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
В наличии базовый проект на VUE-3, и ссылки на плагины https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#carousel.
В списке интересует https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel.
Как понять, совместим ли он с VUE-3?

Когда-то работал с WordPress, и там соввместимость / несовместимость указывалась явно. Здесь не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё указанно явно в packages.json : `"vue": "^2.5.17"`

Для расшифровки этого заклинания смотрим [спецификацию](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) : `^2.5.17 := >=2.5.17 <3.0.0-0`

Следовательно совместимости нет. Она просто не поставится в vue3 проект.

Comment: Благодарю! Так просто, мог бы догадаться сам...

Comment: но почему же не догадался?)

Answer (score 1):

Если в readmi не указано, то я смотрю во вкладке "Issues". В том репе который ты указал, есть такая [проблема](https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel/issues/540)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!